# will systemD timer start alredy running service / process

Tags: timer, systemd

I have a service started by a systemD timer creating a backup of Data every day at 05:00

```
[Unit]
Description=Backup timer
[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 5:0:00
[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Now it looks like this process will run longer than 24 hours to complete the first time.
Will the timmer trigger the next day and start the process again or will it skip, because it is still running?

The service file looks like this and is starting a shell script:

```
[Unit]
Description=Backup service
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/backup.sh
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I just found out myself, the process did not start again.